# How can I customize the "macros" in an Intellij external tool

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, external-tools

I'm hoping to leverage the external tool capability that intellij provides since I want generic tools to share with other developers. The macros option seems quite limited though and very static. I have a tool with which I run by using maven commands. Since there is a limited number of macros and I'm unaware of any means to add or edit them, I can't directly share the tool due to the different install locations of maven on our machines.

Is there a way I can use environment variables (such as $M2_HOME, a maven standard)?

Are there ways to add to the macro list?

Comment: Hi, sorry to dig this up, but I'd like to know if you found a solution to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: No, never got to a solution. I had to do a work around through using a run configuration, which can resolve artifacts from the workspace and knows about the maven installation.

Comment: Vote for this issue if you want better macro support: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92246